# producing all the compositions of n in k parts or less

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to calculate a really weird function for which I have an intricate recursion in java. At some point in the recursion I need to do some calculations using each of the compositions of n into k parts or less.

In other words I need to be able to obtain each of the compositions exactly once and have it stored so that I can do some manipulations with it, obtain a number from it, add it to a counter and then move on to the next composition. I am using java, do you know how I could do this?

As an example consider an algorithm which counts how many times there is a part of size 5 when looking at all the compositions of n of size at most k .

Comment: give an example using number could help too instead words

Comment: very hard to decipher an algorithm without examples, code, or equations

Comment: The compositions of 5 in 3 parts or less are (1,1,3),(1,2,2),(14),(2,3),5.

Comment: I don't undestand what it is that is unclear.

Comment: you efficient you think the algorithm should be ? what have you tried or thought of ?

Comment: Think about how you could write an `Iterator` that does part of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is in python, I'm sure you can make it work in Java easily enough.

Since you want unique partitions -- that is, you consider `(1, 4)` and `(4. 1)` to be the same partition -- it is convenient to generate the components in order. It's slightly simpler to generate them in increasing order.

That means that if we have generated the first `j` components (`j < k`), the last component generated is `p`, and the sum of the components generated so far is `s` (`s < n`), then we can finish off with any partition of `n - s` with no more than `k - j` components whose minimum size is `s`.

In other words, we want a three-argument recursive function. But we also need to think about what we do at the bottom of the recursion when we find a partition. In python, we could just `yield` but in other languages, we could pass a functional through the recursion, and call the functional on the partition. That's probably the simplest solution in either Java or C++, so I'll model the python solution that way. It also uses a fixed-length array, which is bit unpythonic but might work better in Java.

Careful analysis of the recursion will show how to iterate from one vector to the next. But that's of dubious value, IMHO.

```py
# v: vector of size k
# k: max parts
#    (redundant: it's len(v))
# i: number of parts already in the vector
# n: elements left to partition
# s: minimum size of next part
#    (redundant: it's v[i - 1] unless i = 0, in which case it's 1)
# act(v, i): action to call with vector and number of parts
# Invariants: s <= n; i < k
def genpart_helper(v, k, i, n, s, act):
  # We can always use everything which is left
    v[i] = n; 
    act(v, i + 1)
  # If there is more than one part left, and we have
  # at least the twice the minimum number of elements left,
  # we can recurse
  if i + 1 < k:
    # This is python for: "for (int j = n/2; j >= s; --j)"
    for j in range(n // 2, s - 1, -1):
      v[i] = j
      genpart_helper(v, k, i + 1, n - j, j, act) 

# The top-level call. Checks the invariant, creates the vector,
# and calls the recursive function
def genparts(n, k, act):
  if k <= n and k >= 1:
    genpart_helper([0]*k, k, 0, n, 1, act)
```

Partition counts grow fast. There are (if there are no bugs in the above) 596,763 partitions for k = 7, n = 100; 150,224 of them include at least one component of size 5.

For reference, the original python (3.3+), using `yield`:

```py
def genpart_helper(n, k, s, v):
  yield v + [n]
  if k > 1:
    for j in range(n // 2, s - 1, -1):
      yield from genpart_helper(n - j, k - 1, j, v + [j])

def genparts(n, k):
  if k <= n and k >= 1:
    yield from genpart_helper(n, k, 1, [])

>>> for v in genparts(10, 5): print v
...
[7]
[3, 4]
[2, 5]
[2, 2, 3]
[1, 6]
[1, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 5]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a recursive function you need...I've got an idea but you have to try coding it first. Here we want you to try first and when you have doubts come and post the question. However...

I think the key to this problem is to find the base case which would be something like "Given an array of `k` length filled with `1`s, `add 1` to each position until you get `n` when you `sum up all` of the positions. Example:

Find the compositions of length k=3 for n=5.

- findCompositions(3,5)

  - Create new array of lenght 1.
  - Fill it with 1's
  - Add one to each position until you get 5 suming up each position.
  - Here is where the recursion happens, you have to find a way to store that array you created (the one with 1 position), restore it to 1s and add one more position so that now you have 2 positions.
  - i.e. You'll need an auxiliar method findCompositions_rec(k,n,arr,result) where k will recursively go from 1 to k. Arr will change with time, first time will have 1 pos, then 2,then 3...and then k. Result will be a matrix of length [k,k] with all the arrays you created in each recursive call.